# Header doesn't work correctly when resizing web browser

Tags: html, css, menu

I made a header(menu) for my website from the left side to right side ([like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onzrQ.png))

and it works. But when I resize web browser right side of header gets cut down ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llAHr.png))

my code:

```
#header {
 width:auto;
 height:50px;
 background-color:#ffffff;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;

}

#headercontainer {
 width:980px;
 margin:0px auto;
}
```

Comment: Because your headercontainer is set to a specific width.

Comment: I deleted the headercontainer and left only header but nothing changes.

Comment: Then we need to see html.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use px in width, make your width size in percent like

```
#headercontainer
{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use percentage values for better flow. If you want more customization on how you want your website to behave in different screens use media queries. Here is a good **[tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)**

```
  #headercontainer {
     width:75%;
     margin:0px auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#header {
width:100%;
height:50px;
background-color:#ffffff;
margin:0 auto 10px;
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

if you use **auto**, the header will adjust to the required width, so you need **100%** . Of course, just trying to figure what your html looks like since you didn't include it, but in 9 out of 10 situations, this is what you need